# How to disable/remove a desktop widget

Tags: xubuntu, widgets

I added a widget "bouncy ball" to the desktop and accidentaly in its settings set auto-bounce to full. Now it is bouncy accross my desktop really fast. It cannot be hovered to reveal side options. I want to know if there is any other method to disable/remove this particular gadget. (OR to disable all gadgets in extreme case, it is really annoying. I tried to cath it with mouse but no luck, although I am very good fps sniper :) )

Answer (score 0):

Just lock the widgets and it will freeze in place for you

Comment: Actally i tried that but it is not freezing. And in my opinion it should not be, because locking retricts user actions not what whidget is supposed to do.